# Can I tell if a C++ virtual function is implemented

Tags: c++, c++11, overriding, virtual, c++14

I want to be able to tell at run-time if an instance of a class implements a virtual function.  For example:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void func(int x) { <default behavior here> }
    virtual void func2(int x) { <default behavior here> }
};

struct Deriv : Base
{
    virtual void func(int x) override { <new behavior here> }
};

int main()
{
    Base *d = new Deriv;

    if(implements<Base::func(int)>(d)) // This should evaluate true
    {} 

    if(implements<Base::func2(int)>(d)) // This should evaluate false
    {}
}
```

I have seen this but it's dated and there might be a something that c++11/14 has to say now:
[Ways to detect whether a C++ virtual function has been redefined in a derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741271/ways-to-detect-whether-a-c-virtual-function-has-been-redefined-in-a-derived-cl)

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding what you're asking.  Virtual functions are meant to be overridden in derived classes...

Comment: What's the ultimate goal of the exercise? If I add to `Deriv` something like `virtual void func2(int x) { Base::func2(x); }` why exactly do you want this fact - what should by rights be a no-op - to alter the behavior of your program? (And in any case, I don't think you can.)

Comment: I've added some default implementations now, so you can imagine that there _is_ something that these functions are doing.  What they are doing is not germane to my question:  I just want to find out _if_ the functions are overridden or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: No. And certainly not in a portable manner.

The longer answer: actually, the very goal of polymorphism is to make it indistinguishable to the user where the functionality comes from.

Even if the developer does not write code, the compiler might still generate a dedicated version of the function for the derived class (for better optimization). This would throw off even non-portable implementations that would inspect the virtual tables...

An alternative route, however, would be to throw off C++ automatic run-time polymorphism and instead provide an ad-hoc implementation. If for example you were to provide your own virtual table/pointer mechanism, then you would have more control:

```
struct VirtualTable {
    typedef void (*FuncType)(void*, int);
    typedef void (*Func2Type)(void*, int);

    FuncType func;
    Func2Type func2;
};
```

and you could check whether the function pointer is, or is not, equal to the default.

Answer (score -1):

What comes to my mind right now is to have a special "counter" variable, which will take its value based on the implementation and zero if the base-class function is called. I think that this sounds a bit obsolete style though and try to find a better solution in a moment. See the example for now:

```
    struct Base
    {
        virtual void func(int x, int& implemented) {implemented = 0;}

    };

    struct Deriv : Base
    {
        virtual void func(int x, int& implemented) override {implemented = 1;}
    };
```

If the functions are void as in your example, you also can use "return codes" - just return implemented value back.