# How to check if a function has an implementation at run time in C++11?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have only the header file which has the declaration of the functions, but I can't access its corresponding source file. I can change the header file accordingly or I write a function to check if a particular function of a particular class is implemented.

If I made the function in the base class as a pure virtual function, if there isn't an implementation in the derived, then I won't be able to compile it.
Instead, I need a checker to verify its implementation at run time.

Could you please help me understand what needs to be done?

(It's an interview question to which I had to give a solution)

Comment: If you cannot access the source file, you cannot compile it.

Comment: You developed the header? was it given to you for use with a corresponding library ?

Comment: It's an interview question where this was the setup. Both source and header files are present, but I have access to only header.

Comment: Very weird question. Sounds incomplete. If I had been in that interview, there would have been a lot of clarifying questions, because this is not something that's actually possible in C++.

Comment: At runtime... short answer... No. You can get some more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33199082/936269

Comment: "*if there isn't an implementation in the derived, then I won't be able to compile it*"- that should tell you something right there. If the code doesn't compile, it won't run, so there is nothing to check at runtime.